# What is the bast solution in this case

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-models

**I would like to get your recommend.**

```
    // Solution one 
    $total_user=User::count();
    $active_user=User::where('active', 'active')->count();
    
    
    // Solution two 
    $user = User::all();
    $total_user=$user->count();
    $active_user=$user->where('active','active')->count();
```

**Note :** the number of users will become more then at least 1 million.
*Thank all*

Comment: are we here for MCQ ?

Answer (score 2):

i think solution 1 is better

because in solution 2 you are getting all the data from database and then counting them and it costs much more time than just counting them in solution 1

so my choice is **solution 1**

Answer (score 1):

1- First we pull all records with a single query

```
$users = User::select('id', 'active')->get();
```

Notice :
With SELECET, we only bring the selected fields belonging to the user, if there is no need for other important user information for speed.

2- We filter

```
$active_users    = $users->filter(function ($row) {
   return $row->aktive == 'active';
});
```

3- Then we write(in view)

```
Total :{{ count($users) }}
Active :{{ count($active_users) }}
```